# Solving differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my research work I need to find the solution of the following differential equation.

$\displaystyle y'(x)=\frac{y(x)+1}{2 \sqrt{x y(x)}-x},$   $y(0)=0$,

where the solution must satisfies the following conditions.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{y(x)}{x}=1$,
 $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}y(x)=-1$

Is it possible (I mean is there any solution to the problem satisfying to the conditions?)?May someone help me?

Thanks

Vahid

Comment: Integrating factor may help.

Comment: Once more an interesting problem is blocked. Why ? . There is no need for more information on the context to solve it. I am sure that Valid try to do it but he could not solve it by himself, considering the level of difficulty. The general solution cannot be expressed on the form $y(x)$. But it can on the inverse form $x(y)$. The result is a nice formula : $$x=\left(y^{1/2}-\frac{1}{(y+1)^{1/2}}sinh^{-1}(y^{1/2})+\frac{C}{(y+1)^{1/2}} \right)^2$$

Comment: @JJacquelin: It looks like $C=0$ from $y(0)=0$. For what it's worth, checking the limit conditions $y(x)/x\rightarrow 1$ can be possibly done by invoking l'hopitals rule. So you'll have $y'(x)\rightarrow 1$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. You can implicitely solve for $y'(x)$ in terms of $x,y$ and double checking that $y(x)\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @ Alex : That is what I did : roughly $C=0$ and the term $sinh^{-1}(y^{1/2})(y+1)^{-1/2}$ vanishes for $y$ tending to infinity. But I couldn't post the demo of the PDE solving and the limit calculus because the topic was closed at that time.

Comment: @ JJacquelin and Alex: Dear JJacquelin and Alex thank you very much for your responses and useful comments. It is really very nice formula. You helped me very much. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a method to solve the ODE :

[image]

Comment: @ JJacquelin: Thanks so much for your response. This is really nice method and you helped me very much. Thanks again.